# In a login system with 3 levels, what better way to create the tables in the database and login system?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, logic

In a login system with 3 levels, what better way to create the tables in the database and login system?

The three levels are: 'Client', 'Additional' and 'Administrator'.

The 'Client' will access ALL your account details and you can register 'Additional'.
The 'Additional' will have access to only a few details.
The 'Administrator' can register new 'Clients'.

1) Is it safe to have only one login url and let the system check the level of the user to then direct to the correct page?

site. com/login
If Additional OR Client will direct to -> site. com/client
If Administrator will direct to site. com/admin

2) Or the best way is to have a log file for the client and Additional site. com/client/login AND other to the Administrator site. com/admin/login

3) I thought I'd create a table that contains only ID, Login, Password, and LEVEL of ALL users: Clients, Additional and Administrators, and making the query this table to see if the user exists, and what resources are available, then seek data in other tables, depending on the LEVEL, is this a safe practice?

4) I also thought of doing the scan in 3 tables using INNER JOIN to see if the user has permission to access the system. And let ca level data in tables completely separate. It is an efficient alternative?

Other ideas? Alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty open ended question.  You definitely want #1 and not #2.  You don't want to maintain 2 login methods.  Just have 1 login page and decide where the user should go after they log in.

When it comes to #3 or #4, I think you will go farther with #3.  Make your table like this:

```
ID, login, password, client_permission_level, admin_permission_level
```

client_permission_level 1 = "additional"
client_permission_level 2 = "client"
admin_permission_level 0 = "not admin"
admin_permission_level 1 = "administrator"

You can make a more complicated system, but it sounds like this will get you started.  And, you will have the ability to define more levels like "super administrator = 2" or "super client = 3"

Answer (score 1):

1. A single login URL is sufficient if that's how you want it.  You should link the user's authorization level to their authentication (their login name, email, etc.).  Once they are authenticated (logged in) you can get their authorization from the DB and store that information in the session.  The user can't touch this.
2. I don't see any benefit to this, but you could do it if you want.  You still have to check authorization level on each page to determine if the logged-in user is able to see that page.
3. This is not unsafe in any particular way, but it seems to have the relational integrity you probably want.
4. This is not much different, but having a separate table for each access level doesn't make sense.  Unless access capabilities are mutually exclusive, you need at most two tables (one for users and one for levels).  If they are mutually exclusive, you would need a third table for user-level mappings, but that doesn't seem to be the case for you.